# \1 in sed command not working under xonsh

Tags: sed, regular-expression, quoting, xonsh

I don't understand what I'm missing here:

```
$ echo 'testing' | sed -E 's/([a-z]*)ing/\1ing/g'
ing
```

I would expect the output to be `testing` again, since `\1` should be `test`? That input seems to have been swallowed - i.e. the group matched it - but why is `\1` not spitting it back out?

I am on macOS 10.12.2; using xonsh shell and GNU sed v4.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out xonsh (or Python) is swallowing the `\1`, so sed actually sees `'s/([a-z]*)ing/ing/g` and its output is of course correct for that input.

I've [opened an issue here](https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/issues/2097) about it, but the workaround is to use a Python raw string:

```
$ echo 'testing' | sed -E r's/([a-z]*)ing/\1ing/g'
testing
```

This is preferable to escaping (`\\1`) since it would error in a POSIX shell rather than continue with the undesired `\1`.

However, [with thanks to @adqm](https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/issues/2097#issuecomment-272673140), double-quoting and also escaping the backslash is portable between xonsh and bash:

```
$ echo 'testing' | sed -E "s/([a-z]*)ing/\1ing/g"
```

Comment: I would have assumed it saw a 0x01 SOH byte, rather than nothing. (At least, that's what Python does)

Comment: @MichaelHomer I don't really know, but: `echo '\1' | hexdump`: `0000000 01 0a                                          [line end]
0000002` (under xonsh)

Comment: Yes, that shows `\1` is being interpreted as an octal escape for a byte 01, which `sed` will happily accept as part of the replacement. `\\1` should work too then.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Yes, `\\1` is fine, less desirable because it doesn't error in POSIX shells (and continues with a literal `\1`). Maintainer pointed out in Github issue though that double-quoting and escaping (`'s//\\1/'`) will work in both xonsh and bash.